# Using a variable variable name in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, variables

How to use a variable variable name in Visual Basic (.Net)?

```
dim test as String

test = "mysetting"

My.Settings.{test} = "something"
```

Which should be the same as doing:

```
My.Settings.mysetting = "something"
```

Comment: You mean construct a variable dynamicly?

Comment: I want to access a setting by a dynamic name yup

Comment: What's wrong with a dictionary?

Comment: Are dictionaries supported by application settings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eh?

```
My.Settings(test) = "something"
```