# Assigning value to variables based on another variable value

Tags: vb.net, variables

In javascript I can do

```
var thing="MyVar";
var MyVar;
this[thing] = 33;
```

to set the value of a variable based on another value.  So in this case it sets the value 33 to the value of the variable thing.

edit- This will then set the value of MyVar to 33, if I had another value in thing say otherVar it would set the value of otherVar to be 33!

Is there any way to do this in VB.Net?

Comment: you could use the clay project.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332097/using-a-variable-variable-name-in-visual-basic) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356108/using-string-as-a-name-of-a-variable)

Comment: Use `Dictionary(Of String, Integer)` in vb.net

Comment: See [Value Types and Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx) based on current edit

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using Reflection in WinForms that will work with Fields or Properties:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private MyVar As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim thing As String = "MyVar"
        Dim value As Integer = 33
        Try
            Dim FI As System.Reflection.FieldInfo = Me.GetType.GetField(thing, Reflection.BindingFlags.IgnoreCase Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Public Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            If Not IsNothing(FI) Then
                FI.SetValue(Me, value)
            Else
                Dim PI As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo = Me.GetType.GetProperty(thing, Reflection.BindingFlags.IgnoreCase Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Public Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                If Not IsNothing(PI) Then
                    PI.SetValue(Me, value)
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show(value, "Field or Property not found!")
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Unable to Set Value")
        End Try

        Debug.Print("MyVar = " & MyVar)
    End Sub

End Class
```

If you're using this, though, you probably have a bad design to your application.